# How to get asdf and rvm to co-exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, asdf-vm

Is it possible to have `asdf` and `rvm` coexist? If so, how do you set it up? I made a test project to try out `asdf` but it seems that's affecting another existing project that's managed by `rvm`. When I run rails I'm getting:

```
asdf: No version set for command ruby
you might want to add one of the following in your .tool-versions file:

ruby 2.6.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I've came across the same issue while installing `asdf` in `macOS`. I was able resolve it by creating .tool-versions file and adding the ruby version entry. You can do the same by running following command in the terminal.

```
$ echo 'ruby 2.6.1' >> .tool-versions
```

more information can be found here in this [blog post](http://stratus3d.com/blog/2015/11/27/introducing-asdf-the-extendable-version-manager/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the hack I currently use. Running `use-rvm` or `use-asdf` uncomments the respective line in my `~/.bash_profile`, and comments the unwanted line.

```
# RVM
# source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm

# ASDF
. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh
. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash

# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"

use-rvm () {
  sed -i "" 's|^# source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm|source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm|' ~/.bash_profile
  sed -i "" 's|^. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh|# . $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh|' ~/.bash_profile
  bash --login
}

use-asdf () {
  sed -i "" 's|^source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm|# source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm|' ~/.bash_profile
  sed -i "" 's|^# . $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh|. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh|' ~/.bash_profile
  bash --login
}
```

And here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/stephenbaidu/05722bdc4da2860a48cb87e9c106e371)